# Minimize $f(x)=(1+x^TAx)^{\frac1{2}}$ where A is symmetric and non singular

Tags: calculus, optimization

$A$ is not necessarly positive semi-definite, so making the gradient $\nabla f_x=0$, we have that:
$$\dfrac{2x^TA}{2(1+x^TAx)^{\frac1{2}}}=0$$
So
$$Ax=0$$
But since A is non-singular, $x=0$ so $\min f(x)=1$.

My question is since A is not neccesarily positive semi-definite, we can find $x$ such that $-1<x^TAx<0$ and then the minimum value is not at $1$. What did I do wrong?

Comment: Note that $x$ that minimizes $f$ is the same $x$ that minimizes $g(x) = x^T A x$ (if $f$ is defined at that point).

Answer (score 0):

If $A$ is not positive semidefinite, then $f$ is not defined for all $x$. In this case the minimum of $f$ occurs at all boundary points of its domain and has the value 0. The first order condition you wrote down applies only at interior critical points of $f$.